# SourceTree delete all local branches under a specific directory

Tags: git, git-flow, sourcetree

In SourceTree, I have many branches in the directory tree under a custom directory, it looks like this:

```
> File Status
> Branches
   >completed_branches
      >branch1
      >branch2
      >branch3
      ...
> Tags
> Remotes
> Stashes
```

Is there a git command or SourceTree button to delete all branches named `/completed_branches/*`?

Ideally I could just right click the folder in the directory tree and click delete, but that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can run the command, grabbing all branches with `completed_branches`, and executing the delete command on them.

```
 git branch | grep "completed_branches" | xargs git branch -D
```